# Should it be possible to have more than one DocuSign account (DEMO) with the same email address?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a DocuSign integration scenario that has resulted in what look to be multiple DS accounts created using the same email address but different passwords.  I can login w\ the same email address, use two different passwords, and end up in two entirely different accounts.

Comment: Looks like the combination of the email and the username when creating a new account

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is by design.  The DocuSign platform uniquely identifies accounts based on user email and user name combinations.  So creating multiple user accounts under the same email address is allowed.

One other thing to add here, there is also an option in DocuSign called

```
AnySigner
```

which allows you to send signature requests to *AnySigner* recipients which means all you send to is an email address (i.e. no username) and anyone who has access to that email account can sign and complete.  This is a popular option for when you need something signed by anyone in a given department.  For instance, you need a form signed by someone in your Human Resources department which has a common email they use.

Comment: I just want to chime in here and state that in my adventures with DocuSign, one of the main things I wish existed was a "demo" switch that was easier to use. I have multiple accounts and yes you can switch to a demo account using code / server addresses, but in a perfect world there would only need to be a boolean value when creating an envelope. The problem is I have to recreate all exact settings on both accounts, and we end up using paid envelopes for testing.